# Can Strip Tags Be Controlled by If-Else?

Tags: php

If a user enters html tags when we create a form and strip_tags (or something similar) catches it, is it possible to generate an error message like we detected you are trying to use malicious code on our website? But I want to show this only if there is malicious tag usage.

I tried like this but no result;

```
if(strip_tags($data)) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="danger">';
    echo "Security Error!<br>";
    echo "IP Address: " . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Could do something like this `$stripped = strip_tags($data); if($data !== $stripped) { // a tag has been stripped, do something }`, however it might be worth looking into [regexes](https://regex101.com/r/fH3tT0/1) if you want more control

Comment: Trying to determine if the tags used are "malicious" is a hole with no bottom. It would probably be best to generate a simple, general error message like "HTML tags are not permitted in this input".

Comment: @ES  It worked fine when I replaced the strip_tags tag with htmlspecialchars in the format you provided. Thanks for your answer.